# Reading and parsing english with japnese characters from a cav file php

Tags: php

i have a csv file which have lots of lines like this:

```
I Want It All (Tribute to Queen);Dancer (おもしろ♪ Ver.)
Hijo De La Luna (Tribute to Mecano);Perfect (おもしろ♪ Ver.)
You've Got A Friend In Me (おもしろ♪英語 Ver.) [映画『トイ·ストーリー』より]
```

The CSV file has two columns. First one contains only english strings but 2nd one contains mix of english and japnese characters. My code to read this csv file:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<?php 
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    $string = file_get_contents('myfile.csv');
    echo $string;
?>

// My output



��I Want It All (Tribute to Queen);Dancer (J0�0W0�0j& Ver.) 
Hijo De La Luna (Tribute to Mecano);Perfect (J0�0W0�0j& Ver.)
��You've Got A Friend In Me (J0�0W0�0j& Ver.) [ f;u0�0�0��0�0�0�0�00�0�0]
```

If I try:

```
echo "Losing My Religion (Tribute to R.E.M.);I Love It (オモシロ♪ヴォイス ver.)"
```

it displays text with japnese characters correctly. I tried all the solutions, i found on this site, but unable to parse the csv file correctly.

I need help to parse this file correctly. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you check the csv in a editor which show encoding?

Comment: I have created this csv file from excel in "unicode" text file and then changed its extension to csv after replacing tabs with ";"

Comment: If i open it with windows notepad, it shows "UTF-16 LE" at the bottom

Comment: so it its no utf8. there you have it

Comment: Thank you @nbk for all of your help. Its working good now :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue solved by this:

```
$f = file_get_contents('myfile.csv');          // Get the whole file as string
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'UTF8', 'UTF-16LE');   // Convert the file to UTF8
$f = preg_split("/\R/", $f);                        // Split it by line breaks
$f = array_map('str_getcsv', $f);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Glad you got it working. Even though the root cause came out in comments on your original question, it could be helpful for others if you edited the answer and made it clear that the problem was the character encoding. A single sentence stating that the original was UTF-16LE would suffice.